# Cómo evitar impresión de una celda de una tabla

Tags: javascript, html5, css, bootstrap

La sección "modificar" es un `th`. ¿Se puede evitar la impresión (en impresora)?

No se puede usar como `hidden-print`.

[image: captura previa a imprimir - la última columna de la tabla]

La web es un bootstrap con bastantes links y estilos css. Tiene que haber otra forma, algún plugin de print.

[image: captura del código]

---

Esta la script que lo habia hecho para visualizar el contenido de la tabla esta OK pero quiero evitar la sección "modificar" aún no lo logro para no ingresar `:last-child` pues me llevaria mucha demora y mas codigos. ¿algo mejor?

[image: captura del código que está insertando el CSS]

Comment: No entiendo lo de "*me llevaria mucha demora y mas codigos*"... es agregar 1 línea más según [lo que te proponen en la respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/25548/127)... Por otro lado, sería mejor que pegaras el código como texto y luego click en el botón "{  }", y no como imagen.

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no se puede usar como `hidden-print`? ¿No puedes por alguna razón o no funciona?

Comment: @Mariano disculpa, escribo diferente, no muy correcto. Es que soy sordo ademas diseñador gráfico y intermedio en diseño web aún no sé bastante los miles códigos. Lo probé el hidden-print no soporta en el <th>  donde en la sección de una tabla para evitar imprimir. Me extraña porque el sitio web es un Admin LTE (Bootstrap). Lo copie el table tr td:last-child, table tr th:last-child { display:none; } no aparece ni evitar la impresión. eso...como?

Comment: @Lisandro lo que escribiste se entendió perfectamente... A veces nuestros comentarios pueden parecer un poco duros, pero es para respetar el formato del sitio. Me refería a que no entendía por qué no  probar de agregar esa línea (antes de que mencionaras que no funcionaba). Mi recomendación es que intentes lo nuevo que propuso Álvaro en **[este comentario](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25545/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-impresi%C3%B3n-de-una-celda-de-una-tabla?noredirect=1#comment41523_25548)**... Pero si no está funcionando, podrías publicar cómo estás intentando ahora?

Comment: @LisandroContreras, aqui tienes un ejemplo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORjKro yo tambien tuve problemas al tratar de imprimir como tu lo estas haciendo, ya que no me reconocia ninguna hoja de estilos, lo que hice fue hacer un window.print() y agregarle la clase "hidden-print" a todo lo que no queria imprimir, si no te funciona esta clase porque puede ser? Tu bootstrap.css la tiene?

Comment: @FranciscoFernande insolito, lo probé. Me pareció que andaba raro. si lo tengo el bootstrap.css que está incluido quiza es la versión antigua o no está ahi el código incluido. Buena pregunta.! (te funciono ya?).

Comment: @FranciscoFernandez tienes razón, si sale el Bootstrap.css en versión v3.3.6 donde aparecen "hidden-print" debería haber funcionando....! pero nada quizá por tanas javascript o con php impide. No sé como ubicar este problema

Comment: @LisandroContreras Yo uso tambien demasiados javascript y no influye, prueba tratando de sobreescribir la clase, pon algo como "class="hidep"" y en un <style></style> en el head o en un .css pon esto: "@media print {
  .hidep {
    display:none;!important
  }
}"

Comment: ¿Cómo haces la llamada al css de Bootstrap?

Comment: @Mariano pude funcionar pues se me ocurrió otra forma e hice separar hasta colocar los codigos indicados. Resulto! Estoy feliz.! Atte.

Comment: @LisandroContreras me alegro que la hayas podido solucionar. Incluso, sería bueno que publiques la respuesta mostrando la solución.

Comment: @Mariano ya lo publique. Saludos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar un media query para la hora de imprimir haciendo [@media print](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@media), entonces con CSS seleccionar la última columna (ambas con `th` y con `td` por lo que se ve en la captura de pantalla de tu código) y ponerle un `display:none` para que no se muestre. Para seleccionar el último elemento usarías [`last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child).

Entonce sería algo como esto:

```
@media print {
  table tr td:last-child, table tr th:last-child { display:none; }
}
```

Sería mejor si la regla CSS fuera más específica (p.e. si tuviera el ID de la tabla o alguna clase especial que sólo esa tabla tenga) para evitar que se oculta la última columna también en otras tablas de la misma página.

Comment: la probe no me funciona. :C. Supongo  el :last-child no sale alguna, solamente en tabla como el <th>, complicado para hacerla. Voy a mostrar otra imagen para que lo veas es un script que lo había hecho hoy..

Comment: @LisandroContreras esta es la mejor solucion que hay (la que pensaron los tipos que especifican CSS), solo debes asegurarte que el selector que usas este tomando la columna que no quieres incluir.

Comment: @LisandroContreras prueba a añadir solo la linea `table tr td:last-child, table tr th:last-child { display:none; }` dentro de los estilos en el htmlToPrint.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro me costo colocar distintas formas en códigos entonces se me ocurrió otra forma de escribir y separar. RESULTO! Ahora estoy feliz!! por fin...tu consejo me sirvió pero me costo entenderla. Atte.

Answer (score 1):

Estimados, hace un par de horas, por fin lo solucione otra forma para separar los códigos en el script colocando en otra parte mas abajo:

'table tr td:last-child { display:none; }' +
'table tr th:last-child { display:none; }' + 
        '}' +

me funciono! entonces cuando yo oprimo el boton "imprimi", aparezca la ventana de impresión ya que la tabla de la sección "Modificar" desaparece o sea que no fuera imprimible. Es lo que lleva el function DivsPrint es un proceso un poco complejo para que funcione bien con tantos códigos. Lo de hidden-print no cumple bien cuando uno quiere. Esta publicación sirve para otros desarrolladores php, js, etc que estén interesados a estudiarla. Saludos!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me alegro que hayas encontrado una solución pero sigues diciendo que `hidden-print` no te funciona, por eso te preguntaba como llamas al css de bootstrap, si tienes el atributo `media` pero sin el valor `all` o `print` no funcionará.